# PowerShell: Iterate through array to find and return value in proper case

Tags: arrays, file, powershell, text

I'm trying to use the below script to iterate through an array that is built using the contents of a text file and return the matching value, or the argument if no match is found.

```
Param (
[string]$surname
)

$listSurnames = @(Get-Content .\MixedCaseNames.TXT)

# Return $listSurnames

$found = for($index = 0; $index -lt $listSurnames.Count; $index++) {
    if ($listSurnames[$index] -eq $surname) { return $listSurnames[$index]; break } 

    else { return $surname; break }
}
```

Comment: You should look at `Where-Object` and `Select-Object -First 1`

Comment: Also, `return` in powershell is special, probably not what you're expecting it to do.

Comment: "return the matching value, or the argument if no match is found".  What?  Your program will behave identically no matter what.

Comment: `Get-Content .\MixedCaseNames.TXT | Where-Object{$_ -eq $surname}`

Comment: Second to Bacon. You have it returned the matched name or if not.. .the name you tried to match? Why bother even looking through the file then?

Comment: This is a special use case for an identity management system to automatically apply proper case to mixed case surnames. The application passes a value to the script and the script returns the value using proper case if it exists in the "dictionary" file.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent! Thank you all. :)

```
Param (
[string]$surname
)

$findName = Get-Content .\MixedCaseNames.TXT | Where-Object { $_ -eq $surname } | Select-Object -First 1

If ( $findName -eq $null ) { return $surname } Else { return $findName }
```